# Is there any way to cache media files in Browser?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, audio, browser

I want the browser to cache media files. Audio files to be specific.
When a person visits my webpage a big media file is downloaded when they revisit I don't want it to download again.
Any Solution/hack ?

Thanks